# How can we find the corresponding equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let \begin{equation*}v:=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ - 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \ \text{ and } \ w:=\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 3\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

We have the set $$S=\{x\in \mathbb{R} ^3\mid \exists \lambda, \mu:x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+\lambda v+\mu w\} $$

Given that set how can we find, if possible, an equation such that S is the range (set of solutions) of that equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ we need to solve

- $\lambda-\mu=x_1-1$
- $-2\lambda+3\mu=x_2-1$
- $\lambda=x_3-1$

that is

- $\mu=x_3-x_1$
- $3\mu=x_2+2x_3-3$

and then

- $3x_3-3x_1=x_2+2x_3-3 \implies 3x_1+x_2-x_3-3=0$

that is indeed a plane with normal vector $n=(3,1,-1)$ and passing through the point $(1,1,1)$.

Note that we can find the same solution in a simpler way by $n=v\times w$ and then using the condition for passing through the point $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Could you explain to me the last part, i.e. the other method?

Comment: @MaryStar As the set is defined it is clearly a plane passing through the point $(1,1,1)$ and with direction vectors $v$ and $w$ therefore the cross product $v \times w$ gives a normal vector to this plane in the form $3x_1+x_2-x_3=d$ and we can find $d$ by the condition that the plane passes through the point $(1,1,1)$ that is $3+1-1=d \implies d=3$.

Comment: Ahh ok!! Thanks a lot!! :-)